# Digigram VX222HR Not Detected

Tags: sound

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a computer, but it doesn't recognize the extra sound card. With the same hardware, I installed OpenSuse13.1 and it detected my sound card without any problems.
I have run the alsa-info shell script, and the link to that information is [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=eb64d90461490e6b8a5001b19d828a6be83feade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install a package named  alsa-firmware-loader `sudo apt-get install alsa-firmware-loaders`
- You must install the alsa-firmware yourself as there is no package in 14.04 :
  download from Alsa site and extract somewhere (by right clicking in file manager or by `tar xjvf alsa-firmware-1.0.28.tar.bz2`)  :
  [alsa-firmware-1.0.28.tar.bz2](ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/firmware/alsa-firmware-1.0.28.tar.bz2)

Run in a terminal :
`sudo apt-get install build-essential`
`cd` where-you-extracted-alsa-firmware
`./configure`
`make`
`sudo make install`
then reboot.
If problems, you can check that firmware is present here: /lib/firmware/pcxhr/xlxc222.dat

Comment: I installed the alsa-firware-loader package, rebooted the computer, and get the following error from dmesg: "snd_pcxhr: probe of 0000:03:0d.0 failed with error -2"

Comment: edited answers: you must install the firmware itself, i hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Install the soundcard driver packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```