# How do I get the Tascam US122L USB audio interface to work?

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a Tascam US122L (NOT US122). I've spent hours trying to get this to work but it just won't detect in Pulse Audio Volume Control. I've installed the Alsa firmware and Alsa firmware loaders and updated to the latest Kernel (3.16).

I added my user to the audio group and modified the limits.conf file in etc/security/ adding these lines:

> @audio - rtprio 99
>
> @audio - memlock unlimited
>
> @audio - nice -10

cat /proc/asound/modules ~/.asoundrc gives me:

> 0 snd_hda_intel
>
> 1 snd_usb_us122l
>
> 2 snd_hda_intel
>
> got from http://www.nabble.com/tascam-us122l-and-ccrma-td24036395.html
>   thanks to Karsten
>
> The usb_stream plugin configuration
>
> pcm.!usb_stream {
>          @args [ CARD ]
>      @args.CARD {
>               type string
>                default "1"
>         }
>
> ```
>   type usb_stream
>
>    card $CARD
> ```
>
> }
>
> ctl.!usb_stream {
>     @args [ CARD ]
>      @args.CARD {
>               type string
>                default "1"
>         }
>
> ```
>   type hw
>
>   card $CARD
> ```
>
> }

Despite all efforts it just won't get recognized? Any help? I'm going to have to go back to Windows if I can't get this to work :/

Comment: Run "alsamixer" in a terminal, press F6, and do you see your usb soundcard in the list ? If no, try to remove your .asoundrc file and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I can see it but I get "This sound device does not have any controls" and I don't get any sound by selecting it. I should also mention that the green USB light on the US122L is working. As far as I know there are solutions for the US122 but the US122L is an entirely different interface.

Answer (score 1):

> "This sound device does not have any controls"

Sounds like you face a problem similar to what I had getting the FCA610 to work. The device has probably been detected and brought up by ALSA just fine (you can check this be [suspending pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/a/10307/40581) and use the card with `aplay` and `arecord`), but doesn't get picked up by PulseAudio because it cannot find a matching profile for your interface (look at the output of `pulseaudio -vvvv` to find messages of PulseAudio giving up to configure the device after trying for 5 times).

I was pointed to a discussion from January 2014 for a [workaround](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2014-January/019748.html) on the PulseAudio mailing list and was able to get my device working.

Note that the topic was about firewire devices. For USB devices you would have to use a matching udev rule with vendor and product id for your device, mine looks like this:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1397", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="multichannel.conf"
```

you can find the vendor end product id of USB devices by using `lsusb`, here is the example for the Behringer FCA610:

```
Bus 003 Device 051: ID 1397:0003 BEHRINGER International GmbH
```

To create and edit files on the commandline you can use `nano`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> saves changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> quits.

There is also a patch from David Henningson that adds functionality to properly detect such devices, but you would have to compile PulseAudio yourself to test this (which I didn't find enough time for).

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu so I have no idea which command I should use for USB devices. This is what pulseaudio -vvv shows: (edit: can't post it, "too long by 1500 characters"?)

Comment: Just updated my answer with additional information.

Comment: Based on the information from lusb I typed: 'ATTRS{idVendor}=="0644", ATTRS{idProduct}=="800e", ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="multichannel.conf"' and I got '
ATTRS{idVendor}==0644,: command not found'

Comment: @Airegin This line needs to be added to `/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules` and you have to create the file `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/multichannel.conf` with the contents from the mail with the workaround. After that, restart your computer to let the udev rules take effect. Remember to reenable pulseaudio if you disabled autospawning.

Comment: I just did this and rebooted but unfortunately I still get "This sound device does not have any controls".

Comment: @Airegin It doesn't exhibit software controls, because it has hardware ones. You should be able to see the device in Pulse Audio Volume Control and use it.

Comment: It's still not showing up in Pulse Audio Volume. I installed the alsa firmware from the website as well, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The Tascam US-122L is only supported via the `usb_stream` access method which `aplay` cannot work with.  You need to use the instructions (in another answer) for creating a `usb_stream` access in your `.asoundrc`.

The only application I know that actually can open devices like that is `jackd`.  It may have at one time offered `-dusb_stream` as access method: no idea.  At least some old instructions seem to imply that.  But I only got is working with `-dalsa -dusb_stream:1` (use the correct card number).  Once you have `jackd` running (I use `-r96000 -p512 -n2` I think), you can go from there.

For Ardour and other jack-centric applications, you are set.

On the Ubuntu desktop, the least painful way for most applications will be to go via Pulseaudio.  Install the `pulseaudio-module-jack` package and then create a script (and make it executable) as `~/bin/pulsejack` with the following content:

```
#/bin/sh
if [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
    killall jackd 2> /dev/null
    jackd "$@" & sleep 2
fi
pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=2
pactl load-module module-jack-source channels=2
pacmd set-default-sink jack_out
pacmd set-default-source jack_in
```

This script can be called without arguments to make a running jackd instance the default in/output for Pulseaudio.  If you give it arguments, it will kill any running `jackd` and start a new `jackd` with the options you give it.

When `jackd` dies, Pulseaudio will usually be smart enough to revert to an existing soundcard, I think.

It's possible to let Alsa go via `jackd` with suitable `~/.asoundrc` file, but on Ubuntu this additional redirection to access stuff from the Pulseaudio-centric desktop does not seem useful.

As a last note: I use `jackd1`: I don't know whether or not `jackd2` deals gracefully with the `usb_stream` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your sound card with **Jack audio server** and  your .soundrc  was ok
(From   [alsa sound card matrix Module-usb-us122l](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-usb-us122l):  "*This module is intended for use with the jack driver "usb_stream".* " )

I suppose that you want to make music  recording so the best way is to install  **Ardour** (best multitrack recorder for Linux) , Jack audio server(jackd)  will be installed as dependency (say "yes" when asking about realtime privileges, reboot) .

Install also **qjackctl** , launch it , click  "settings" button, then click ">" near "interface box" to select "usb_stream" (which is created by .asoundrc). In the same way  select also "input " and "output" device.

Then launch Ardour, create project, and test recording: usually Ardour connect automatically tracks as needed.
*On a track , press shift+e to get a mixer strip for setting track connections and level*

You can look this thread : [Digitech USB multi-effect with Jack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530956/digitech-usb-multi-effect-with-jack/530984#530984) for some tips    (in case you have too much delay or to much xruns (clicks) , or **problem with non-jack compatible software**)

The best info for Ardour recording is there: [Ardour manual](http://en.flossmanuals.net/ardour/)

Comment: Did you get Alsa-firmware from alsa web site and then compile and install it , as it is not in Ubuntu 14.4 repository ?

Comment: Is there a tutorial to compile the Alsa-firmware? I'm new to Ubuntu so I wouldn't know how to do that. I just use it to listen to music. My laptop's audio output is broken. I have already tried everything with Jack but I always get errors and I couldn't resolve it despite trying every solution that's been suggested to other experiencing the same errors.

Comment: Also, you need to install alsa-utils (which is in ubuntu 14.4 standart repository) to  get "usx2yloader" firmware loader

Comment: Thanks, how do I do this exactly though?

Comment: Ok, for firmware, do like this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493122/digigram-vx222hr-not-detected/493167#493167     . The easiest way would be to install Ubuntu Studio where everything is  ok for jack . But for just listening music, you can use internal soundcard, no ?

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. I can't use my internal soundcard since my laptop's output jack is broken.

Comment: At the first command in your link I get: "E: Unable to locate package alsa-firmware-loader"

Comment: @Airegin It seems to be `alsa-firmware-loaders` on 14.04.

Comment: Okay so I figured it out and did everything above succesfully but nothing changed. Still doesn't show up in Pulse Audio Volume Control. Also, if I read correct somewhere else it seems that usx2yloader does not apply to the US122L.

Answer (score 0):

Tried once more with audiojack but this is what I get:

> Mon Oct  6 21:59:17 2014: Starting jack server...
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:17 2014: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:18 2014: ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop > /ReserveDevice1/Audio1": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio1
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:18 2014: ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio1 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio1
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:18 2014: ERROR: Audio device usb_stream:1 cannot be acquired...
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:18 2014: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:18 2014: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:18 2014: ERROR: Failed to open server
>   Mon Oct  6 21:59:19 2014: Saving settings to "/home/david/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
>   21:59:21.155 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
>   Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
>   Cannot connect to server request channel
>   jack server is not running or cannot be started

Comment: it means that pulseaudio or another jackd already use the soundcard:you can try to disable pulseaudio temporarily , copy and run successively this 4 commands in a terminal (remove quotes "")  :  `mkdir ~/.pulse` `echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`  `killall pulseaudio`    `killall jackd`  then relaunch jackd  (do you see the proper device in qjackctl settings ? )

Comment: Thanks, I did as you told but when I start up Qjackctl I get this: `17:35:25.325 Patchbay deactivated.
17:35:25.329 Statistics reset.
17:35:25.364 ALSA connection change.
17:35:25.769 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
17:35:25.777 ALSA connection graph change.` Also yes, the audio interface shows up in the settings as "hw:US122L". Also tried "usb_stream:1" but to no avail.

Comment: Well, instead using qjackctl, you could try to start jack with this command in a terminal  `jackd -vR -p50 -dusb_stream -dhw:CARDNR -r44100 -p128` , ignore errors, and try to play a sound  using Audacity (in which you can choose Jack as audioinput/output).  From here : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131839  , it appears that you will not have volume control , also you will have errors, but it can works with jack compatible software : so, if it is ok with jack+audacity, the 2nd step would be to run jack thru pulseaudio with  pulseaudio-module-jack: not impossible

Comment: I can't start jack with the command, I get "unknown driver" in the terminal.

Comment: yep, I missed the CARDNR which is 1 in your case, the correct command would be `jackd -vR -p50 -dusb_stream -dhw:1 -r44100 -p128`

Comment: Still getting "Unknown driver "usb_stream". Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it but I'm about to give up :)

Comment: ok, no problem .